# Can I transfer arbitrary points to any answer I am deeply grateful for?

Tags: support

Let's say I am totally stuck and it so happens I found an obscure answer that helps me solve my problem. An upvote (1 point) does not seems to cut it, I want to donate my points to the person... let's say 10, or 100 points... how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: I am not asking a new question (hence I am not offering bounty). I just found an answer to an old question that was answered perhaps years ago...

Comment: Giving extra points to an existing answer, is a valid reason to award a bounty. It's even one of the standard reasons in the bounty menu.

Comment: You can still use a bounty to reward that answer; **Reward existing answer** is one of the options.

Comment: It's Bounty or Nothing! "Awarding arbritary point" sounds like lets build a Rep market for sock pupet where they can trade rep without any regulation unit. And upvote is not 1 point.

Comment: "An upvote (1 point) does not seems to cut it" - why not? It's not a payment or a thank you note. Assuming you mean the problem is obscure rather than the answer, it likely won't affect too many people making it less useful in the broad sense so it is to be expected that the answer won't receive hundreds of upvotes. That's just the way it is. We need to keep it neutral and honest, which means containing both outrage and excitement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a specific type of bounty for just that use case, called "reward existing answer". As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/), one of the valid reasons to offer a bounty is:

> Reward existing answer
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional
>   bounty.

You can start a bounty on any non closed question that does not currently have a bounty active, and by choosing that reason you can award the bounty to any previously posted answer a day after starting it.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, but close enough. When I said arbitrary points I was thinking 5, or 10, or 20... but this will do I guess.

Comment: @RosdiKasim do you think it will be fair if you have the possibility to give more than 1 upvote/downvote? .. all of use have the same weight, why someone would be able to give more points? the system will simply reflect nothing: You can give +20 to an answer because *you only* find it usefull vs 20 users  giving +1 because all of them found the answer usefull. How to make the difference between the first and last case?

Comment: @temani, I worded my question wrong, I wanted to transfer my points to answers I deemed very helpful to me. In that context I think it is fair since I lose my points... just like how bounty works. I didn't mean to say I have more weights than others.

Comment: @Rosdi, when you offer a bounty, let it run for the full 7 days. This way, people involved in the Q&A may receive extra upvotes from visitors that find their posts useful.